# How the Stefan's law will change if the body isn't a black body?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, thermal-radiation

The [Stefan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) for black body radiation where energy varies with the forth power of the temperature but what will happen if the body isn't black body? Would it be still forth power of temperature that varies with energy or some other relationship will stand between?

Comment: See [Emissivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stefan Boltzmann law for radiant heart flux $q$ from a black body, as you point out, is:

$$q = \sigma T^4$$

For a non-black diffuse thermal emmitter (called a "grey body"), a parameter called emissivity  $\epsilon$ is defined, which takes values between 0 and 1, and captures what fraction of a blackbody's spectrum is emmitted by the grey body.  Thus

$$q = \epsilon \sigma T^4$$

Generally $\epsilon$ is empirically measured and given in tables for various materials (closer to 1 for dialectrics/insulators, and closer to 0 for metals). And $\epsilon$ can be a function of wavelength, temperature, and other factors, depending how high fidelity you want to make your grey body model.

Specular (mirrorlike) reflectors and other objects can have a totally different functional relationship of heat flux on temperature.